Set dynamic end date for user activity in power bi rest api connector
I’m creating a usage report of our workspaces using the power bi rest api connector.
I am using a custom connector from this GitHub link,
https://github.com/migueesc123/PowerBIRESTAPI
The connector is using Power BI REST APIs internally and loading usage data from the service in the form of a table.
I’m looking for a way to set a dynamic end date (today) in the “get user activity” function so it’s not dependent on a manual input/ hard coded start and end date.
Setting a daily refresh on this report in the power bi service so I’d like yo see the latest user activity for the day in the power bi service.
It would be great if i can get help setting a delta load so it keeps the history of the user activity and just loads current day.
If this can’t be achieved, I’d also like to know why.
Thank you in advance.
enter image description here
I tried using date.from(datetime.localnow()) in place #date(2024,5,1)), without any luck. I get an error about the format. I am running out ideas or further creativity and would appreciate any help.
